# Windows 10 audio headset detection Issues

Tags: windows-10, drivers, dell-latitude

I'm not sure if the title fully explains the situation.

Basically sound refused to play through my headset once I connected them

I've re-installed most of the drivers on my (new) machine about what seems like an infinite amount of times. (Downloading various version of drivers, and swapping between older & newer Realtek drivers, as well as the default Microsoft HD Audio drivers.)

Currently I've got something working... but for the life of me, it does not make sense at all.

[image]

When I disable the auto detection on the audio socket, I'm able to get sound played through my headset, when I disable it, sounds gets redirected to the speakers... **WUT!?** :/

My playback devices... also quite strange, I'd expect to see headphones here, not just a single speaker/headphone combination... (I'm guessing it's a new thing)

[image]

Has anyone encountered this before, and is there a (known) solution other than days of tinkering?

(Specs: Windows 10 / Dell Latitude E5550 / Realtek HD Audio)

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of your `Playback Devices`?

Comment: @Ramhound, see updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no software fix for this. I believe this was a hardware issue.

My thinking is that, the driver was meant to access the hardware auto detection, thus by disabling it, and specifying a output device, my sound would work.

We also tested on exact same spec machines and had no issue.  I ended up returning the laptop to the supplier whom re-issued another laptop (that didn't have the same problem).